# how can I determine memory usage of a giant c# data set

Tags: c#, .net, memory, bigdata, ram

I have a giant data set in a c# windows service that uses about 12GB of ram.

```
Dictionary<DateTime,List<List<Item>>>
```

There is a constant stream of new data being added, about 1GB per hour. Old data is occasionally removed.  This is a high speed buffer for web pages.

I have a parameter in the config file called "MaxSizeMB".  I would like to allow the user to enter, say "11000", and my app will delete some old data every time the app exceeds 11GB of ram usage.

This has proved to be frustratingly difficult.

You would think that you can just call GC.GetTotalMemory(false).  This would give you the memory usage of .net managed objects (lets pretent it says 10.8GB).  Then you just add a constant 200MB as a safety net for all the other stuff allocated in the app.

This doesn't work. In fact, the more data that is loaded, the bigger the difference between GC.GetTotalMemory and task manager.  I even tried to work out a constant multiplier value instead of a constant add value, but I cannot get consistent results. The best i have done so far is count the total number of items in the data structure, multiply by 96, and pretend that number is the ram usage.  This is also confusing because the Item object is a 32byte struct.  This pretend ram usage is also too unstable.  Sometimes the app will delete old data at 11GB, but sometimes it will delete data at 8GB ram usage, because my pretend number calculates a false 11GB.

So i can either use this conservative fake ram calculation, and often not use all the ram I am allowed to use (like 2GB lost), or I can use GC.GetTotalMemory and the customer will freak out that the app goes over the ram setting occasionally.

Is there any way I can use as much ram as possible without going over a limit, as it appears in task manager?  I don't care if the math is a multiplier, constant add value, power, whatever.  I want to stuff data into a data structure and delete data when I hit the max setting.

Note: i already do some memory shrinking techniques such as using a struct as the Item, list.Capacity = list.Count, and GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration).  Those seem like a separate issue though.

Comment: Task Manager isn't always accurate. It is a best guess. Furthermore you cannot control entirely how much memory can be consumed or put on "reserve" (technically) as its all down to the GC - that is the point on GC, it does memory management. It also depends on references you are holding to your objects (I see a List<Item>) and how much footprint there is for GC to determine when to clean up or which objects go to another generation. There are many factors to consider here but comparing with Task Manager is not accurate

Comment: Sounds like it might be easier just to set a limit on the number of objects rather than memory since you suggest you know how big they are.

Comment: Don't try and measure memory. It is hard to measure and there is a garbage collector.  And an object needs contiguous memory so how big the collection can be varies.   Decide how many rows you want max and manage by that.

Comment: I think it is not proper to store so much(12GB) data in memory as the high speed cache of the web pages, first are all the data needed? second, what happened if the server crashes?

Comment: The data is a cache of several hours of all civil aircraft radar and gps data across the united states. it is used like a DVR to replay air traffic events which is rendered as svg vector data on top of an interactive map. If the server crashes, our users are redirected to the sister site in another city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` and monitor your current process memory usage and available memory, based on this, your application should decide to delete something or not..

Comment: ProcessMonitor is not a good measure of memory.  If you clear memory it will often not show it.

Comment: Are you talking about "Process Monitor v3.05" from microsoft technet? That seems to be a gui app. Should i launch the exe as a process from my windows service with command line arguments? That looks like it would work, but slightly annoying, and might require admin permissions. It does look like a good solution though.

Comment: Actually I am talking about `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` This can be used to get the RAM usage statistics. `System.Diagnostics` has many clases which can be used to get process related information.

Comment: ok, i will look into System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter. If that works i will feel like an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems
Garbage collection
Getting a good measure of memory
What is the maximum

You assume there is a hard maximum. 
But an object needs contiguous memory so that is a soft maximum.

As for an accurate size measure you could record the size of each list and keep a running total.
Then when you purge read the size and reduce from that running total.

Why fight .NET memory limitations and physical memory limitations
I would so go with a database on an SSD
If it is read only and you have known classes then you could use like a RavenDB
Reconsider your design

OK so I am not getting very far with managing .NET memory limitation that you are never going to tame. 
Still reconsider your design.
If your PK is a DateTime and assume you only need 24 hours put one per dictionary per hour as that is just one object.
At the end of 23 hours new the prior - let the GC collect the whole thing.

Comment: yeah, I suppose it is more like a soft maximum.  As for counting, yes that is what I am doing. It turns out that 2 billion items is sometimes 8GB ram, and sometimes 11GB ram. That is the frustrating, confusing part. If anyone knows why that happens, let me know.

Comment: How do you know it is sometimes 8GB and sometimes 11GB?

Comment: i watch the item count written to a log file every few seconds, and look at task manager. usually the first time i hit 2 billion, its about 11GB, then it deletes a 30min chunk and it drops to 9GB. then the GC runs and it drops again to 7GB (this is all sort of expected). The weird part is the second time it hits 2 billion, its down around 8GB.  if I run GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration) a lot, like every 2 mins, then the first max hit isn't so extreme, and i can tweak my max count a little higher.

Comment: Well, a database on ssd is way, way slower than ram, unless RavenDB just caches the DB in ram like Redis does. Also, the project is done and it works really well. I am just worried about using slightly too much ram and causing paging. Also, i just really thought using an item count, when i really wanted ram usage was kinda hax.

Comment: I may reconsider the design in the future. Maybe i will rewrite the whole thing in c++ and run it on debian, that would be awesome. Unfortunately, I have more projects to work on. But I do agree with you. Windows and .net is not my favorite platform for serious number crunching. oh well.

Comment: SSD is way way slower?  And what database today does not use a ram cache?  You can run some of them IN ram and you are not subjected to the .NET object size limit.

Comment: Other pieces of this project use mssql and mongoDB.  Those are nice. mssql is fast and smart caches really well. This is just different. i don't really need a database for a short replay feature. Actually, we used to use a db for this feature and it was unbearably slow. And yes, ssd is orders of magnitude slower than ram, always, in every possible test ever.

Comment: sorry Blam, you seem smart, and you have a ton of rep, i may be misinterpreting your statement.

Comment: I am just direct.  It seems like you are spending a lot of effort to manage .NET object size limitation and there are some really fast options out there that don't have that limitation.  Since your data does not mutate you could go with read optimized.  Pushing stuff off the queue will take time.  GC takes time.   I will add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is super simple.

```
var n0 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
var n1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
var n2 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64;
float f0 = ((float)n0)/(1000*1000);
float f1 = ((float)n1)/(1000*1000);
float f2 = ((float)n2)/(1000*1000);
Console.WriteLine("private = " + f0 + " MB");
Console.WriteLine("working = " + f1 + " MB");
Console.WriteLine("virtual = " + f2 + " MB");
```

results:

```
private = 931.9096 MB
working = 722.0756 MB
virtual = 1767.146 MB
```

All this moaning and fussing about task manager and .net object size and the answer is built into .NET in one line of code.

I gave the answer to Sarvesh because he got me started down the right path with PerformanceCounter, but GetCurrentProcess() turned out to be a nice shortcut to simply inspect your own process.

Comment: Which did you use out of PrivateMemorySize64 and WorkingSet64? Both seem to give very similar results.